# Accessing pubsublite message attributes in beam pipeline - Java

Tags: apache-beam-io, google-cloud-pubsublite

We have been using PubSubLite in our Go program without any issues and I just started using the Java library with Beam.

Using the PubSubLite IO, we get PCollection of SequencedMessage specifically: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsublite/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsublite.proto.SequencedMessage

Now, from it I can get the data by doing something like:

```
message.getMessage().getData().toByteArray()
```

and then doing the normal conversion.

But for attributes, I cannot seem to get it correctly, just the value. In Go, I could do:

```
msg.Attributes["attrKey"]
```

but when I do:

```
message.getMessage().getAttributesMap().get("attrKey")
```

I am getting an Object which I cannot seem to convert to just string value of it. As far as I understand, it returns a Map<String, AttributeValues> and they all seem to be just wrapper over the internal protobuf. Also, Map is an interface so how do I get to the actual implementation to get the underlying value of each of the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The SequencedMessage attributes represent a multimap of string to bytes, not a map of string to string like in standard Pub/Sub. In the go client, by default the client will error if there are multiple values for a given key or if any of the values is not valid UTF-8, and thus presents a map[string]string interface.

When you call `message.getMessage().getAttributesMap().get("attrKey")`, you have a value of type [AttributeValues](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsublite/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsublite.proto.AttributeValues) which is a holder for a list of ByteStrings. To convert this to a single String, you would need to throw if the list is not of length 1, then call `toStringUtf8` on the byte string element with index 0.

If you wish to interact with the standard Pub/Sub message format like you would in go, you can convert to this format by doing:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsublite.CloudPubsubTransforms;

PCollection<SequencedMessage> messages = ...
PCollection<PubsubMessage> transformed = messages.apply(CloudPubsubTransforms.toCloudPubsubMessages());
```